# Absolute continuity of a random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability

If $X$ is Uniform(0,1) and $ Y = \min \{ X, 1/2 \}$, would $ F_Y$ be absolutely continuous? I'm having trouble visualizing the distribution of $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not continuous at all: it has a jump at $1/2$ since $P(Y=1/2) = 1/2$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "linked" with the distribution of X at that point then?

Comment: $F_Y(x) = F_X(x)$ for $x < 1/2$, $1$ for $x \ge 1/2$.